# Bootstrap 3.1.1 Thumbnail Slider

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I use this code, but it makes a vertical image scroller on my web site. How might I change this to make it horizontal? I took this code from http://www.bootply.com.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-12">
         <h1>Bootstrap 3.1.1 Thumbnail Slider</h1>

        <div class="well-none">
            <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">

                <!-- Carousel items -->
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="item active">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
                              <div><div>Header</div><div>Subheader</div></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6"><a href="#x"><img src="http://placehold.it/500x500" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6"><a href="#x"><img src="http://placehold.it/500x500" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6"><a href="#x"><img src="http://placehold.it/500x500" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!--/row-->
                    </div>
                    <!--/item-->
                    <div class="item">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6"><a href="#x col-xs-6" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!--/row-->
                    </div>
                    <!--/item-->
                    <div class="item">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!--/row-->
                    </div>
                    <!--/item-->
                </div>
                <!--/carousel-inner--> 
                <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left fa-4"></i></a>

                <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right fa-4"></i></a>
            </div>
            <!--/myCarousel-->
        </div>
        <!--/well-->
    </div>
</div>



$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myCarousel').carousel({
    interval: 0
    })

    $('#myCarousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function() {
        //alert("slid");
    });


});

.thumbnail {
  display: block;
  padding: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  border-radius: 0;
  border: none;
  background-color: none;
}

.carousel-control {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 15%;
  opacity: .5;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: none;
}
.carousel-control.left {
    background-image: none;
}
.carousel-control.right {
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
  background-image: none;
}

.carousel-control {
  padding-top:10.25%;
  width:5%;
}
```

Comment: I copied this over to [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amullins/NW2YS/). What exactly is wrong with it? The scrolling is horizontal. Did you want the elements in each scroll section to be horizontally aligned?

Comment: i wanna look like this http://s5.picofile.com/file/8129705918/image_scroller.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stared at this way too long before finally realizing that if two identical programs produce two different results, there must be different external dependencies. Sure enough, the example is pulling from [MaxCDN Bootstrap 3.2.0](http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css). Change your bootstrap stylesheet link to this, and the grid mark-up actually works as shown in the Bootply example.

I had originally pulled in [the jQuery-UI bootstrap css](//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-ui-bootstrap/0.5pre/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css). I imagine you had a similar difference in Bootstrap sources.

I'd link a fiddle, but you've already got that code.

Comment: Max CDN, linked above. That's what the bootply post uses.

Comment: There is an syntax error on line 10 of Bootstrap 3.2.0.

Comment: Sorry, it was 3:30 AM in my time zone when you posted your last comment. Is there really a syntax error in bootstrap? What is the error?

Comment: I'm sorry if you don't have a solution yet. What is the error now?

Comment: no, you helped me; there is no problem with my code; i used your code Bootstrap 3.2.0, and now there is no error, thank you